# .Net Core Template for VS 2019

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-templates

I am trying to create a solution template for .net core 3.1 api by following the below link
https://www.aka.ms/netcore-templates

Here is my folder structure

[image: Here is my folder structure]

I am running the `nuget.exe` and `dotnet new --install` everything under "Root Folder".

Once the installation is completed, I could see template gets created successfully in the command line. I am also able to create the project using this template through command line `dotnet new <template> -o NewProject`. The new project which I created also gets build successfully in VS 2019.

However, I am not able to see the same template in Visual Studio new project dialog. I have Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition 16.9.0 and the tools/options/product features "select .net core project template" is selected. I restarted visual studio after installing the template.

Can someone please tell me what could be the problem? why the template is available in the command line and and not appearing in visual studio.

Please let me know if I need to provide any additional information.

Comment: Did you add the template to the Documenten\Visual Studio 2019\Templates\ProjectTemplates directory as a zip?
See docs if not already looked at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-multi-project-templates?view=vs-2019

Comment: Hi @JeremiedeVos , we don't need to add the zip file to the template folder for the .net core template created through the .template.config. please find the below link and it was not mentioned https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-cli-templates-in-visual-studio/